# Sequelize, "where" condition in many includes

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model called `Customer` that may or not have many `animals` linked to it (`models.Customer.hasMany(models.Animal)`).
I'm trying to search for all the Customers name and Animals name. If I search for `Tes` it should return all the Customers LIKE `Tes%` but also all the Customers NOT LIKE `Tes%` but that has an animal name LIKE `Tes%`

```
Customer.findAll({
    limit: 25,
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [
            { name: { [Op.like]: searchQuery } },
            { lastName: { [Op.like]: searchQuery } },
        ],
    },
    attributes: ["id", "name", "lastName"],
    required: false,
    order: [
        ['lastName', 'ASC'],
    ],
    include: [
        {
            model: Animal, attributes: ["id", "name"], required: false, where: { name: { [Op.like]: searchQuery } },
        }
    ]
})
```

My query works, but it only returns Customer with name matching the query.
I tried to add `{ "$Animals.name$": { [Op.like]: searchQuery } }` in the Customer conditions, but it return an unkown column.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Did you keep `include` option when you add `{ "$Animals.name$": { [Op.like]: searchQuery } } ?`

Comment: I did yes of course

Comment: Could you add the generated SQL?